# Como guardar el ID de una tabla mysql en una variable php dentro de un modal que esta en el archivo index.php

Tags: javascript, php, html, modal

**[image]**
Muy buenas comunidad, necesito una ayuda ya que estoy iniciando con el mundo de la programacion, quisiera que me ayudaran a como guardar el id de una tabla mysql en la linea 823, por defecto lo deje como 3 y me toma esa posicion de la tabla de la base de datos pero no quiero poner manualmente un numero si no que me tome el id del registro que he seleccionado previamente, los  datos se muestran en un modal.

Comment: Bienvenido a [so] tu pregunta tiene problemas de formato . Corrígela Te recomiendo leer [ask] antes de publicar una pregunta

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

Las líneas 824 y 825 deberían estar en una sola línea, te puedes ahorrar algunos inconvenientes si tu sentencia la manejas en una sola línea.

Por otro lado, en PHP el el [operador de concatenación](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) es el punto (**.**), entonces para poder concatenar tu sentencia sql con el valor de tu variable **$id** necesitas hacer algo así:

> "Select * FROM table WHERE id=" . $id

Nota como la variable **$id** queda fuera de las comillas de la sentencia. A continuación te dejo el fragmento de código para que puedas comprobar si te es funcional o no.

```
$id = 3;
$stmt = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT producto_ID, producto_IMAGEN, producto_NOMBRE, producto_PRECIO, producto_DESCRIPCION, producto_CATEGORIA FROM dantex_productos WHERE producto_ID = " . $id);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Lo de la línea 824 y 825 están así solo porque si la dejaba en una sola línea no podia tomar el capture para hacer esta pregunta, obvio va en una sola línea. La otra cosa es que me parece que no me entendiste o no me diste la solución al problema, yo quiero que en vez del ID 3 que le puse 3 por hacer la prueba, en vez de ese número quiero que me tome el ID del registro que seleccione para que me pueda mostrar los datos de ese ID seleccionado en el modal. Todo eso está en un solo archivo index.php